# How to remove a specific number from string in PHP

Tags: php

How can I remove a specific number from string, if the number is repeated I just need to remove it one time.

```
$string = "1 3 5 15 5";
//Remove 5
$valuetoremove = "5";
$newvalue = "1 3 15 5";
```

I tried 
str_replace but this remove all the numbers repeated.

```
str_replace("5"," ","1 3 5 15 5");
$newvalue = "1 3";
```

Comment: Use `implode()` to convert the string to an array. Use `array_find()` to find the index of the first occurrence of the number. Use `array_splice()` to remove it. Use `implode()` to convert that back to a string.

Comment: @Barmar: I think `explode` , `array_unique` then `implode`.  Their description doesn't match the code.  They say remove repeated number but show `5` as a given to remove.  I'll assume repeated.

Comment: So what about `$string = "1 3 5 15 5 5";` You still just need to _remove it one time_? To result in `1 3 5 15 5`?  You need to more clearly state what the rules are.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple numbers repeated on the string, I just need to remove it once. I'm trying the explode, unique, implode.

Comment: `str_replace()` has an optional argument telling it the number of replacements to make, so you can limit it to the first replacement. However, If `15` is before `5` it will turn that into `1` instead of removing `5`. You could use `preg_replace()` to match whole words, it also has a count argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically want to just remove it one time, then I guess this is what you're after

```php
$string = "1 3 5 15 5";
$valueToRemove = "5";
$exploded = explode(" ", $string);
// $exploded = ["1", "3", "5", "15", "5"];
$key = array_search($valueToRemove, $exploded, true);
if ($key !== false) {
  unset($exploded[$key]);
}
$newValue = implode(" ", $exploded);
```

Comment: That is true, please flag this post as too helpful, it was in particularly bad form for me to provide a useful answer to make someones life easier on a Q&A site :P

Comment: I think this is a community to help each other and answer questions. If you do not want to be part of this the best option is to start your own Q&A site.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users for the reason for my earlier comment and why this question was closed.